# how to change the navbar height only at ios devices?

Tags: html, css, ios, reactjs, responsive

Hello (sorry about my English )

I built a navbar on bottom of the page for my website and I saw in iOS (its on responsive mode)
when I'm start to scrolling down the navbar start to be smaller because he down a bit the question is how I can give height to my navbar when I scrolling down and how to make it only for IOS devices
(the website its in react if its matter)

this is the code I did for my navbar

````
.navbar-footer {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 2;
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
    @supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  /* CSS specific to iOS devices */ 
}

@supports not (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  /* CSS for other than iOS devices */ 
}
```

It works because only Safari Mobile implements -webkit-touch-callout: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/[developer.mozilla][1]-webkit-touch-callout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%5Bdeveloper.mozilla%5D%5B1%5D-webkit-touch-callout)

Please note that @supports does not work in IE. IE will skip both of the above @support blocks above. To find out more see https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/08/using-feature-queries-in-css/. It is recommended to not use @supports not because of this.

What about Chrome or Firefox on iOS? The reality is these are just skins over the WebKit rendering engine. Hence the above works everywhere on iOS as long as iOS policy does not change. See 2.5.6 in App Store Review Guidelines.

Warning: iOS may remove support for this in any new iOS release in the coming years. You SHOULD try a bit harder to not need the above CSS. An earlier version of this answer used -webkit-overflow-scrolling but a new iOS version removed it. As a commenter pointed out, there are other options to choose from: Go to Supported CSS Properties and search for "Safari on iOS".